# PHP int value is dependent on system

Tags: php, int, bigint

I use same code in different machine.

Ubuntu 64

```
$test = 51339780210;         
echo (int) $test; die; //result : 51339780210
```

Centos 32

```
$test = 51339780210;         
echo (int) $test; die; //result : -199827342
```

Why these result is different?

Comment: Is by any chance the second system 32-bit ?

Comment: It depends ONLY on the fact if the system is 32bit or 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many bits are both systems? This can be the difference between 32-bit system and 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Execute "uname -a" on both systems. I'd assume the ubuntu says something with x86_64, which means it's 64 bit, while Centos says i686, which is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

```
   The size of an integer is platform-dependent ...
```